# How to pull a large amount of data from mariadb in a fast manner when workload is IO bound

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**Important to know information:**

We have a database table 'cdrs'

```html
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint(12)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| server_id       | tinyint(2)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| cdr_id          | bigint(13)    | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| user_id         | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| transaction_id  | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sip_id          | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| call_type       | tinyint(2)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| did_from        | char(24)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| did_from_alias  | bigint(18)    | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| did_to          | char(24)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| did_to_alias    | bigint(18)    | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| call_status     | char(12)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_time      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |                |
| duration        | decimal(13,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| billed_duration | decimal(13,3) | NO   |     | 0.000   |                |
| rate            | decimal(10,4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| amount          | decimal(10,4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| usf             | decimal(10,4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| total           | decimal(10,4) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| country         | varchar(96)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country_id      | int(8)        | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| code            | varchar(8)    | NO   |     |         |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

With the following indexes

```html
+---------+------------+------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+---------+------------+------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| cdrs |          0 | PRIMARY          |            1 | id             | A         |   573346816 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          0 | PRIMARY          |            2 | start_time     | A         |   573346816 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_cdr_id         |            1 | cdr_id         | A         |   573346816 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_user_id        |            1 | user_id        | A         |      158909 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_call_type      |            1 | call_type      | A         |       19887 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_transaction_id |            1 | transaction_id | A         |   143336704 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_total          |            1 | total          | A         |      163953 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_start_time     |            1 | start_time     | A         |    24928122 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_call_status    |            1 | call_status    | A         |        9877 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_sip_id         |            1 | sip_id         | A         |      353481 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_did_to         |            1 | did_to_alias   | A         |   286673408 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| cdrs |          1 | i_did_from       |            1 | did_from_alias | A         |    57334681 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+---------+------------+------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
```

**The Problem:**

Currently in production this table has more rows then the max value of int(hence why the id is bigint)

This table grows in size everyday by GB and as the company expects to grow those GB will turn into 10s of GB and eventually hundreds of GB

Right now the database is running on raid 10 SSD's

Taking the following scenario

Its the first of the month and a customer wants to pull his records for last month so he can bill his customer.

This query will be directly IO bound because none of the data will exist in the Innodb buffer because this is the first time it is queried.

So lets say our query looks similar to

`SELECT * FROM cdrs WHERE user_id='<SOME_USER_ID' AND start_time>=1654099200 AND start_time<1656691200`

So we are grabbing all the call records for this user from the beginning of the month to the end of the month

In a test this resulted in 52,627,431 rows for one client and took 50 seconds to just run the query

`SELECT Count(*) FROM cdrs WHERE user_id='<SOME_USER_ID>' AND start_time>=1654099200 AND start_time<1656691200;`

I have looked around for different databases and I just don't know what direction I need to go in but we need the ability to pull these records in a much faster fashion currently just pulling an hour of records takes 30mins for some customers with higher volumes

**Possible solutions that we have tried**

**Use a summary table**

I know one suggestion will be using a summary table which we already use one but it does not help in this instance because customers need the actual data contained in this table

**Partition the table**

We partition the table by the month and the results are still to slow

I have tried to use a columnstore engine in mariadb and this actually gave us significant performance improvements in some areas but not specifically for getting the CDR's to our customers

I wish I could use Redis for this because Redis is lightning fast but tables take up 1.1T of data currently and will only continue to grow

Eager and open for a solution

Comment: `show create table cdrs` shows both the columns and indexes in a much more readable form

Comment: it looks to me like you need just a (user_id, start_time) index.  I see start_time is included in your primary key, but that won't help you (and indeed I can think of no advantages for doing that)

Comment: @ysth - Not just a secondary index, but the primary key.  (I briefly discuss "clustering" in my answer.)

Comment: @RickJames totally agree, I was criticizing only the `(id,start_time)` primary key.

Answer (score 0):

**PRIMARY KEY**

```
WHERE user_id='<SOME_USER_ID>'
  AND start_time>=1654099200
  AND start_time< 1656691200;
```

is best handled by

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, start_time) -- in this order.
```

If a "user" can have two rows with exactly the same `start_time`, then

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, start_time, id) -- in this order.
INDEX(id)
```

Otherwise, consider getting rid of `id`.

Having the PK *start* with `user_id` puts all the rows for a given user clustered together, making that (and similar) queries faster.

Having the *second* part of the PK be `start_time` significantly helps with that `BETWEEN`.

**PARTITION** -- There are many "wrong" ways to use `PARTITIONing`.  To discuss that, please provide more details.  In general, Partitioning does *not* provide any speedup.

The main reason I see for using `PARTITIONing` is if you need to delete "old" data; `DROP PARTITION` is immensely faster than `DELETEing` millions of rows.

**Data size**

Many of the comments I will make here relate to how much disk space the table is/will take.

By "clustering" the data properly, I/O is decreased when the table is much bigger than RAM.  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  How many GB will the table have before you start purging it?

Clustering may give you 10x speedup.

**CHAR** -- This is a fixed length datatype; it should be used only if the data is 'always' the length specified.  Otherwise, it wastes space.

**INDEXes** -- Don't blindly add indexes for lots of columns.  Only have the ones you need.  "Need" comes from the queries you will be running.  Consider using "composite" indexes where appropriate.

It seems like most `SELECTs` would include `WHERE user_id = ...`; if that is correct, I would expect many of the indexes to be "composite", starting with `user_id`.

**Country** -- Don't include a 4-byte INT and a multibyte string; simply have a `CHAR(2)` for the standard "country_code" and, if needed, a lookup table to map to strings.

**Midnight** -- When building a daily or monthly report, what should happen to a call that spills across midnight?

**Summary tables** -- A summary table should have worked quite well for your data.  Please explain what data the report needs; I'll help redesign the summary table.

If the summary is all details for all calls for the month, then that is not a "summary"; the clustered PK gives you a 10x improvement.

If "summary" means daily subtotals, then let's see the details.

**Numeric types** -- INT takes 4 bytes; BIGINT takes 8 bytes.  The "13" in `bigint(13)` has no meaning.  If the value is really limited to 13 digits, then consider `DECIMAL(13,0)`, which takes 6 bytes.  See also `MEDIUMINT` and `SMALLINT`.  `DECIMAL(13,3)` takes 7 bytes.

**ENGINE** -- Do use InnoDB.

Comment: Would you actually be available for a consulting job with the company? That way you can take a direct look at the database and provide tips on how we can do better

Comment: while `index(id)` is sufficient to allow auto increment, I would recommend `unique(id)` instead.  the 3-part primary key would prevent dup ids with the same user id and start time, but better to go ahead and guarantee id is always unique.

Comment: @JoséphFlames - Yes.  Reach me at mysql at rjweb dot org .  The task you mention is my expertise.

Comment: @RickJames dont use linkedin much but i sent you a connect waiting for you to accept so i can message you :)